# Deprecated API Usage Apple

Tags: app-store-connect

Box iOS sdk is not supporting the webView class of UIWebView.

Error : After uploading the App to appstoreconnect,we receive this message:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps

So how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Okay.  Do you have a question for us?

Comment: WKWebView is needed or not

Comment: that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information

Comment: Use WKViewKit in place of UIWebView